# .htaccess redirecting from root url

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url

I have a folder contains `php` files as following:

```
view/
-a.php
-b.php
-c.php
```

I'm trying to redirect root url to view folder like `domain.com/a.php` to `doman.com/view/a.php`.

> .htacess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*?).php view/$1.php
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   RewriteBase /
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^(.*).php$       view/$1.php [L,QSA]
```

You can also do this editing your DocumentRoot at apache httpd.conf:

> DocumentRoot "current_path/view/"